# SQLQuery script in Delphi looking for a specific date

Tags: sql, delphi, dbexpress, delphi-10.1-berlin

How to prepare Query in Delphi before running the statement?

I have a value from GUI control for filtering data.

```
Select FULLNAME, DATE, WORKORDERNO From OE WHERE Date = "<Value_From_EditBox>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a parameterized query. The Delphi documentation contains a pretty good set of tutorials on working with databases in your application. If you're asking this basic a question here, you probably should find them.

```
MyQry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT FullName, Date, WorkOrderNo FROM oe WHERE Date = :Date';
MyQry.ParamByName('Date').AsDateTime := StrToDate(Edit1.Text);
MyQry.Open;
```